# read/write a file on remote server java

Tags: spring

**hi i want to write in file exist in remote server 
i try this code i cant read content of file but i cant't find any code to write any help**

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftpClient.setFileType(2);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            String remoteFile1 = "/anomalies_t24/conf/trac.ini";
            InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFile1);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);


                list = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());


                //list.forEach(System.out::println);
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                      if (list.get(i).contains("projet.options =")) {
                          list.set(i, list.get(i) + "|" + nom);

                          break;
                      }
                  }



            inputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using or would like to use Apache Commons Net 3.6 FTPClient API,
then below method is used to append file:

```
public boolean appendFile(String remote, InputStream local) throws IOException
```

Or you may find other useful methods from below javadoc link of Apache Commons Net API:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Comment: how i can use appendFile for specific position